# Gradle maven plugin: uploadArchives cannot find /tmp/gradle_empty_settings xml

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, repository, nexus

I just switched from Eclipse and Maven to Android Studio and Gradle for my Android projects.

Now I would like my Jenkins server to build and upload release versions to my self hosted Nexus server.

For this I added those lines to my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = "de.myapp"
version = '2.2.0'

android {
    ...
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            maven {
                name "snapshot_repo"
                url "http://192.168.178.85:8081/nexus/content/repositories/myapp_snapshots"

                credentials {
                    username  "admin"
                    password  "admin123"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The building process works fine but I can't upload any project to the Nexus server without getting this strange message:

> :myapp_testname:assembleDebug
>   :myapp_testname:uploadArchives
>   Upload http://192.168.178.85:8081/nexus/content/repositories/myapp_snapshots/de/myapp/myapp_testname/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.xml
>   Upload http://192.168.178.85:8081/nexus/content/repositories/myapp_snapshots/de/myapp/myapp_testname/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.xml.sha1
>   [ant:null] Error reading settings file '/tmp/gradle_empty_settings56173630026020664.xml' - ignoring. Error was: /tmp/gradle_empty_settings56173630026020664.xml (No such file or directory)
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 3 mins 31.555 secs
>   Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to SUCCESS
>   Archiving artifacts
>   Finished: SUCCESS

I will get two ivy files on the repository but nothing more.

It seems like gradle cannot create the tmp file. But I don't know why.

When I execute this on my local windows machine I will get the same error (just with another tmp folder)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found the problem and the solution:

I'm using several flavors and buildTypes (free/premium and debug/release) in my app.
This means there is no real "default" variant.
In this case you need this line in your module's build.gradle to publish your different build types

```
android {
    ...
    publishNonDefault true
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are your .pom files generated with this fix? Because that part does not work for me.